# Nextjs13 when try to proxy by rewrite option in next.config , it goes redirect rather than rewrite

Tags: next.js, fetch, next.js13

When I try to proxy by using rewrites option in next.config, it doesn't rewrite but redirect.
but what a interesting is it happens when using some word for source like 'board' or 'collection'

below is the code which occur issue

```
[ fetch code ]
  const getCategory = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/board/popup/popup', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEMP_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

[ next.config code ]
  rewrites: async () => {
      return [
        {
          source: '/board/:path*',
          destination: `https://board.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_DOMAIN}/:path*`,
        }]
  }
```

and it's the network tab when I fetch api using rewrites
[image: network tab when sent fetch]
as you can see in that image, it's not rewriting but it's redirecting with a lot of "_nextjs_original-stack-frame" fetch which I have no clue what it is. and also the redirect has error cause it lost headers

but if I change to source for rewrites from '/board/:path*' to '/anyOtherWords/:path*', it is rewriting well normally.

```
[fetch code]
  const getCategory = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/anyOtherWord/popup/popup', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEMP_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

[next.config code]
 rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/anyOtherWord/:path*',
        destination: `https://board.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_DOMAIN}/:path*`,
      }
    ]
   }
```

and here's the successful result
[image: successful fetch]

Things I tried

- I tried to add "trailingSlash: true" option for solving this issue following alexmojaki's answer on here [https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36219](https://stackoverflow.com) but it didn't work
- I checked backend code and there were nothing special.
- Empty cache and hard refresh on browser. but it didn't work

I'm just guessing if there are some reserved word for 'board' or 'collection' or there are some cache remained for the '/board/:path*' source on rewrites option in next.config file.
I want to know why this happens